# Why won't my custom QHeaderView allow sorting

Tags: qt, sorting, qheaderview

I implemented my own QHeaderView extending from QHeaderView.

After I set sorting enabled on the QTableWidget that uses this view, I still cannot sort.  For what it is wroth, the table is initially sorted by the first column.  If I do not set the horizontal header to my custom class, sorting is performed.

The only overloaded methods are the constructor (forces horizontal) and sizeHint().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to call

```
setClickable(true);
```

in the constructor.  Now sorting is possible again.

For Qt5:

```
setSectionsClickable(true);
```